# Keydown has a delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    notedo.play()
  }
});
```

which essentially just plays a sound on keypress, however I'm trying to create sampler and there's a delay pressing a key. Anyway I can get around this? as well as being able to play multiple keys at once?

I am also using this in my HTML side:

```
<div class="black key" data-note="G#3" onclick="notedo.play()"></div>
```

So when clicking on my div element above it plays the notedo variable in javascript. I'm trying to find a way to implement key pressing to play the sound as well.

Comment: Are you sure the delay isn’t in the playback of the audio? Or a silent part at the beginning of the audio file? Is the audio fully downloaded first too? What does your JS profiler say? Is this a hardware keyboard or soft/on-screen keyboard? What about using WebHID instead of DOM keyboard events? Are any other event-handlers running?

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that it isn't delay issue. It seems when pressing the key down it plays the audio immediately however I want to press it again while the audio is still playing to play the audio immediately from the start again.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue which I think was getting confused with delay.

I was actually trying to play the same audio immediately after I press the same button.

I ended up using this!

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    notedo.play()
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    notedo.play();
    notedo.currentTime = 0
  }
});
```